# webNavigation has probably no permission, but i dont know why

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

As the title says, the console says that chrome.webNavigation is undefined so it cannot read the property of onDOMContentLoaded.

Error : *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onDOMContentLoaded' of undefined*

Here are my codes:

#### manifest.json

```
"manifest_version": 2,

"background": {"scripts": ["background.js"]},

"permissions": ["tabs","webNavigation","http://*/*","https://*/*"],

"content_scripts": [
{
   "matches": ["*://*/*"],
  "js": ["jquery.js", "content.js"]
}
```

#### background.js

```
chrome.webNavigation.onDOMContentLoaded.addListener(function() {

chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function(tab) {

    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab[0].id, {event:'event'});
});
});
```

Thanks for help.

## EDIT:

Ok i solved it, i had a syntax Error in my manifest.json..so it never got to permissions, thanks anyway : )

Comment: Visit `chrome://extensions/` and press Ctrl + R. New permission changes are only applied after reloading an extension.

Comment: yes i know, thats not the problem. It has no problem with "tabs" permission, cause i used it with a click event and that worked.Maybe that helps...

Comment: The `tabs` API is unusual; it can be used without the `tabs` permission.

Comment: Ok now i tried one with webRequest and this doesnt work too, same problem...can the browsersettings block some things?

Comment: No, that's not possible. It's almost certain that you did not correctly reload the extension.

Comment: I'm not having that error.  I am, however, having to set a timeout before sending the message.

Comment: Ok i solved it, i had a syntax error in my manifest.json...thanks anyway : )